# Is it possible to find out the hosts in the known_hosts file?

Tags: ssh

I would like to see what hosts are in my known_hosts file but it doesn't appear to be human readable.  Is it possible to read it?

More specifically there is a host that I can connect to via several names and I want to find out what the fingerprint I expect for it from my known hosts file.

Update: I'm using OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009

A line from my known_hosts file looks something like this,

```
|1|guO7PbLLb5FWIpxNZHF03ESTTKg=|r002DA8L2JUYRVykUh7jcVUHeYE= ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAFADAQABAAABAQDWp73ulfigmbbzif051okmDMh5yZt/DlZnsx3DEOYHu3Nu/+THJnUAfkfEc1XkOFiFgbUyK/08Ty0K6ExUaffb1ERfXXyyp63rpCTHOPonSrnK7adl7YoPDd4BcIUZd1Dk7HtuShMmuk4l83X623cr9exbfm+DRaeyFNMFSEkMzztBYIkhpA2DWlDkd90OfVAvyoOrJPxztmIZR82qu/5t2z58sJ6Jm2xdp2ckySgXulq6S4k+hnnGuz2p1klviYCWGJMZfyAB+V+MTjGGD/cj0SkL5v/sa/Fie1zcv1SLs466x3H0kMllz6gAk0/FMi7eULspwnIp65g45qUAL3Oj
```

Comment: If it is not hashed you can use: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236192/extract-hostnames-from-non-hashed-ssh-known-hosts/

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You've got `HashKnownHosts` set to "`yes`" in your `ssh_config` file, so the hostnames aren't available in plaintext.

If you know the hostname you're looking for ahead of time, you can search for it with:

```bsh
ssh-keygen -H -F hostname
# Or, if SSH runs on port other than 22. Use literal brackets [].
ssh-keygen -H -F '[hostname]:2222'
```

Here's the relevant section from the [`ssh-keygen(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html) man page:

> ### `-F` *hostname*
>
> Search for the specified hostname in a `known_hosts` file, listing  any
> occurrences found.  This option is useful to find hashed host  names
> or addresses and may also be used in conjunction with the  `-H` option
> to print found keys in a hashed format.

Comment: Does hash known hosts essentially mean it's not possible?  i.e. I need to know the name of the host in order to look at it's info?

Comment: @ColinNewell That's right, you need to know the hostname(s).  It's a security measure to keep an attacker from harvesting hostnames/IP addresses of other boxes you frequent if your machine is compromised.

Comment: Don't be scared when there is no output at all, but try not the full qualified hostname but the hostname instead.

Comment: Not sshd_config, but ssh_config.

Comment: @pdo - your command does not always work. If the host has SSH on  port other than `22`, then the format in `known_hosts` is different. Then you have to use the following command:  `ssh-keygen -H -F [host.example.com]:2222`

Comment: I wanted to find the rsa key for a specific host, so I ran this: `ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -F <hostname>`

Comment: I'm considering using this in a script, so I was testing return values. When it successfully finds a match, it returns one, and when it fails it returns 1. Any idea what it's supposed to be returning? The manpage doesn't state anything under the -F or -H flags, nor is there a section about what it returns.

Comment: @Ungeheuer That is strange. I see the same behaviour. You could do `test $(ssh-keygen -H -F ssh.vps4.mikkel.ca | wc -l) -gt 0`, which will exit 0 on a match, 1 on no match.

Comment: Oh, the square brackets in `'[hostname]:2222'` are *literal*. I unconsciously parsed them as indicating a variable to be substituted! If you are trying to find a server that's on a port other than 22 you *do* have to include those square brackets.

Comment: @Ungeheuer that bug seems fixed now. I get a return value of 0 for a successful match with `OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020`

Comment: This answer is helpful, though this part isn't true: "You've got `HashKnownHosts` set to "`yes`" in your `ssh_config` file"

Answer (score 24):

For future searchers, this article (non-disclaimer: I'm not affilated) has a relatively simple Perl script to brute-force hashed IPs and hostnames in `known_hosts`.

http://blog.rootshell.be/2010/11/03/bruteforcing-ssh-known_hosts-files/

It allows starting from a particular IP address.  It could also easily be modified to use a dictionary.

Also, in June 2014, the John the Ripper project [added support for known_hosts cracking](http://www.openwall.com/lists/john-users/2014/07/02/2), which can take advantage of multiple CPU cores, GPUs, dictionary mangling, etc.

Overall, it's an exercise similar to password cracking, with a somewhat more predictable (or at least constrained) target space.

For private IPs, you can use this nmap snippet to generate a dictionary of all RFC1918 IP addresses to use as a dictionary:

```
nmap -sL -Pn -n 192.168.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12 10.0.0.0/8 |\
    grep '^Nmap scan report for' | cut -d\  -f5 >ips.list
```

If public IPs are included, it may be more efficient to use rules. [This hashcat ruleset](https://github.com/johnjohnsp1/hexhosts/blob/master/ipv4.hcmask) may need additional work to adapt to work with JtR, but does most of the heavy lifting and should give you a starting point.

Hostnames are more idiosyncratic to the user and environment, but there are trends in host naming. Fully qualified hostnames can be correlated in DNS, /etc/hosts, shell history, etc. with any discovered IP addresses. Since destination systems can be entirely unrelated to the host system, public dumps of common domains and hostnames can be acquired from the DNS data from various Internet-wide scanning efforts (such as Censys).

Using John the Ripper is likely to be more efficient and scale better than the native SSH solution in the accepted answer for all but the most simple cases.

Comment: There is also a python implementation with similar features, can be found at: http://blog.tremily.us/posts/known_hosts/

Comment: Lars Nordin, thanks for the tip. I submitted Remily's info to the John the Ripper team, and they added support for this in bleeding-jumbo: http://www.openwall.com/lists/john-users/2014/07/02/2

Comment: And here's how to do it with hashcat: http://up1ink.tumblr.com/post/132370869368/bruteforcingknownhostshashcat

Answer (score 13):

Does `ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts` help? It shows the fingerprints for each host in that file. (Using `-v`you also get nice little treasure maps, e.g.

```
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|        .        |
|       + .       |
|      . B .      |
|     o * +       |
|    X * S        |
|   + O o . .     |
|    .   E . o    |
|       . . o     |
|        . .      |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Not in the strictest sense no, it's all still base64.  pdo's explanation of it being hashed suggests it's a one way thing so I guess I'm stuck unless I know the hostname.

Comment: That helped me. What I wanted specifically was a combination. To find the previously verified ssh fingerprint, you can run: `ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -F <hostname>`

Comment: uh, `ssh-keygen -l -F <hostname>` is even simplier

Answer (score 7):

Use the `-l` option to `ssh-keygen` to list fingerprints, and the `-F` option to search for a hostname in your `known_hosts` file.

```
$ ssh-keygen -l -F sdf.org
# Host sdf.org found: line 835 type RSA
2048 6e:cd:53:4f:75:a1:e8:5b:63:74:32:4f:0c:85:05:17 |1|9J47PEllvWk/HJ6LPz5pOB2/7rc=|ld0BtQh5V3NdhBHBwR/ZqSv8bqY= (RSA)
```

You can use `ssh-keyscan` to compare the fingerprint in your `known_hosts` to the one from the server.

```
$ ssh-keyscan sdf.org | awk '{print $3}' | base64 -d | openssl md5 -c
# sdf.org SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
# sdf.org SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
no hostkey alg
(stdin)= 6e:cd:53:4f:75:a1:e8:5b:63:74:32:4f:0c:85:05:17
```

Answer (score 1):

There is host string/ip at the beginning of each "known_hosts" line (before the "ssh-dss" or "ssh-rsa" string):

```
hostgn6 ssh-dss AAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAACBAIfGV4+/28Zr+dT/i+ifydUBS0dMRUjCtExIThOj3Yexynu+wSRGjMm4GfF+og2kAljZyUjhBFeM+WYbJzcDSDB [...] ==
yumyumn6.dik6.dir2g.some.net ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAACBAIfGV4+/28Zr+dT/i+ifydUBS0dMRUjCtExITh [...] ==
```

Comment: ...and thus `awk '{print $1}' known_hosts` does the trick.  Be aware that servers listening on non-standard ports end up as, say,  `[some-server]:5555` in `known_hosts`.

Comment: Unfortunately not in mine.  Mine looks more like base64 encoded data.  The data is also pipe delimited in my file.

Comment: Which ssh software are you using then (we were assuming that you were using the almost-standart openssh software) ?

Comment: I've added more details to my question.

Comment: As stated by @pdo, your sshd as "HashKnownHosts" set to on, which may appear a bit anal, but security concern it is. And of course there is no way to simply reverse the hashes and get the hostnames from your "known_hosts".

Comment: What I don't understand is how ssh decides when it needs to make a new entry, as opposed to reuse an existing one. In my `known_hosts` file there are clearly multiple entries for the same host, for example `ec2-54-221-174-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com,64:ff9b::36dd:ae02` , `ec2,54.221.174.2`, `2607:7700:0:19:0:1:36dd:ae02` . Yes, the IP addresses are different here, but in other cases ssh seems able to coalesce lines with multiple IPs into a single line. How does this really work? (RTFM pointer appreciated.)