# Extract hostnames from non-hashed ssh known_hosts

Tags: bash, ssh, awk, bashrc, gawk

I would like to extract hostnames/ips from .ssh/known_hosts file in all (known) format conditions:

- Hostname only `hostname pubkey`
- Hostname with ip: `hostname,1.1.1.1 pubkey`
- Hostname with ip that is not reverse and custom port: `[hostname]:1234,[1.1.1.1]:1234 pubkey`
- Safely ignore hashed hosts, if any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F'[ ,:]' '/^[0-9a-zA-Z]/{sub(/\[/,"",$1); sub(/\]/,"",$1); print $1}' ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Used as ssh auto complete in my project [bgrc](https://github.com/benvaljean/bgrc) for those who do not wish or cannot install bash-completion.

Comment: Hmm, fails on IPv6 addresses, returning only the first octet.

Comment: @thrig Can you confirm what it looks like in the known_hosts file and I take a look at it

Comment: `2001:db8::1 ssh-rsa ...` or with ports `[2001:db8::1]:1234`, possibly as CSV with hostnames or IPv4 equiv.

Comment: If only complete ipv6 addresses are matched this is relatively easy, the regex in the Net::IPv6Addr perl module can be used. To match incomplete ipv6 everything between the (square) brackets can be captured: `[[ $i =~ ^[\[]([^,]+)[\]]`. I will work to incorporate the logic into the above awk and then remove the colon from the field delimiters.